# Intercepting standard "Save All" Visual Studio command

Tags: c#, events, visual-studio-2015, event-handling

I am writing the functionality of a deprecated VS Addin into a Package extension for VS 2015.

In the package extension there is a tool window with a toolbar containing some buttons which execute commands. Amongst these, there is a 'Save All' button, which should not only save the files of the solution to the local disk, but also save the files back to the database to which the user is connected. This works fine at present. However, the user will probably click on the standard Visual Studio 'Save All' button, and expect the files to be written to the database as well. So I need to intercept the standard 'Save All' command and add my method that handles the saving of the files to the database.
I managed to do this, but it is just not as neat as I think it should be. I'm not knowledgeable regarding events and delegates. I read up about it, and then I don't use it often enough, and then I forget what I read and so on.

So the functionality for the 'Save All' toolbar button in the package extension is found as follows in the Package.cs file. In the Initialize method:

```
protected override void Initialize()
    {


        OleMenuCommandService mcs = GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
        if (null != mcs)
        {

            CommandID saveAllCommandID = new CommandID(new Guid(Guids.guidConnectCommandPackageCmdSet), (int)PkgCmdIDList.cmdidSaveAllCommand);
            command = new OleMenuCommand(new EventHandler(SaveAllCommandCallback), saveAllCommandID);
            command.BeforeQueryStatus += BeforeQueryStatusCallback;
            mcs.AddCommand(command);


        }

        visualStudioInstance = (DTE2)this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));          

        CreateEventHandlers(visualStudioInstance);

    }
```

and here is the SaveAllCommandCallback:

```
    private void SaveAllCommandCallback(object caller, EventArgs args)
    {
        SaveAllDocuments();
        OutputCommandString("In SaveAll Command Callback");
    }
```

SaveAllDocuments is the method responsible for saving the files to the database. I don't think it is necessary to post that.

My attempt to intercept the standard Visual Studio "Save All" button's command is as follows:
In the Initialize method above, there is a method CreateEventHandlers:

```
private void CreateEventHandlers(DTE2 visualStudioInstance)
    {

        Events2 evs = visualStudioInstance.Events as Events2;
        Commands cmds = visualStudioInstance.Commands;

        Command cmdobj = cmds.Item("File.SaveAll", 0);
        saveAllCommandEvents = evs.get_CommandEvents(cmdobj.Guid, cmdobj.ID);
        saveAllCommandEvents.BeforeExecute += new _dispCommandEvents_BeforeExecuteEventHandler(m_SaveAllCommand_BeforeExecute);


    }
```

And then here is m_SaveAllCommand_BeforeExecute:

```
private void m_SaveAllCommand_BeforeExecute(string Guid, int ID, object CustomIn, object CustomOut, ref bool CancelDefault)
    {
        SaveAllDocuments();
        CancelDefault = true;
    }
```

As you can see, it calls SaveAllDocuments and sets CancelDefault to true, which I think signals to the caller that it has interfered with the command and not only been a listener. Should it be set to true?

Anyways, my main question is, how do I link saveAllCommandEvents.BeforeExecute to the SaveAllCommandCallback? I think it would be better to have SaveAllDocuments called from only one place, in SaveAllCommandCallback, but I don't know how to link the callback to the event of the standard Visual Studio "Save All" button.

I guess this should be simple if one is familiar with events and delegates, but I'm not. I just have a feeling that what I'm currently doing could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not to use `CancelDefault = true;` in `m_SaveAllCommand_BeforeExecute` and just call `SaveTheFilesBackToTheDatabase()` from it.

Comment: Why do you recommend I remove it?

Comment: @Igavshne Because you don't want to prevent saving files to disk when a user selects File.SaveAll.